# How do you set the command timeout in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, command-timeout

I have a datareader source firing some sql which takes longer than 30 seconds to run, so it's timing out.  I can not find a command timeout property on the datareader source component, or the data flow task.  Is there some way to set a longer command timeout in SSIS?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right Click on the Datareader source and click edit.
Go to Tab Component Properties and under Group Custom Properties has CommandTimeout

Comment: All I have for properties on the Custom Properties group is SqlCommand  and UserComponentTypeName

Comment: I am using VS.net 2005. But I think that shouldn't be an issue with VS.net 2008. Its strange that property is missing. Try OLE Db Data Source. See if that has the property.

Comment: Yup,  the OLE DB Source has a command timeout, but the DataReader Source does not!

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a hotfix for this, I don't know if it applies to you or not: [Hotfix link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956911)

Comment: This says its for the web service task, does it apply to the datareader source component too?